# Conflict between `ruby` and `xeCJK`

Tags: xetex, xecjk

In my preamble I call `xeCJK` and `ruby` in order to add ruby text to Japanese characters. I'm compiling with `xetex`.

Someone mentioned in an earlier post that `ruby` calls `CJK` causing a compile error (the document looks fine, though).

How do I avoid this? The documentation for `xeCJK` is written in Chinese so I can't read it and I can't  find `ruby`'s documentation (lots of stuff on the programming language, though).

---

Before we go any further, here is a MWE as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ruby}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
   %\setCJKmainfont{MS Mincho}
   %\setCJKsansfont{MS Gothic}
   %\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
   %\setsansfont{Calibri}


\begin{document}
   %\ruby{日}{に}\\
   %\ruby{本}{hon}\\
   %語\\
   Latin text.\\
   \textsf{Latin text.}
\end{document}
```

The comments are there so that you can play around and see if the errors change given different types of input.

The first error I get (with comments as they are) is:

```
"xparse/command-already-defined"! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
```

Swapping the order of `xeCJK` and `ruby` produces no errors! Why?

Is there a better package than `ruby` which will *never* conflict with `xeCJK` or  a better selection of packages that is less prone to errors?

Comment: I'll add my preamble once I get home, I'm just on mobile at the moment.

Comment: What's the error? And please add a complete minimal example. We don't need your entire preamble. We do want a complete, small document we can compile to reproduce the issue. The code you post should produce the exact error you report when we compile it.

Comment: You can't avoid `ruby.sty` calling `cjk.sty`. It is itself part of the `cjk` package and depends essentially on `cjk.sty`. As far as I can tell, you either find an alternative to `ruby` or you use `cjk` rather than `xecjk`.

Comment: How can `ruby.sty` be part of `cjk.sty` if they are separate packages? Are they always distributed together then?

Comment: 'package' is unfortunately ambiguous. They are separate packages in the sense that they are separate `.sty` files. But they are part of the same package in the sense that they are part of a single set of files which constitutes a package in CTAN's sense. Here is the [MANIFEST](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/language/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.4/MANIFEST) for `cjk`, which lists all files provided by the package, including `ruby.sty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the error by loading ruby *after* xecjk.

Be aware that this is cheating: You are only preventing xecjk to *detect* that you are loading cjk. It is quite possible that you get other conflicts -- ruby and cjk is not written for xelatex. But it could work, if you adapt the \ruby command as shown in this answer:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178858/2388